# How do I use CSS to let one or more elements fill remaining space?

Tags: html, css

I have an input form with a column on the left that contains the label for the input, and a column on the right with the input element.  Right now it's a table (sorry):

```
<tr>
  <td>Header</td>
  <td><input /></td>
</tr>
```

I have a couple of inputs that I'd like to take following form:

```
<tr>
  <td>Header (Extra)</td>
  <td><input /> (<input />)</td>
</tr>
```

In the first case, input should expand to fill the whole column.  In the second, I'd like the 2 inputs to expand as wide as they can to be the same size, and fill the column.

Ideally, my display would look like

```
Row 1         _______________________
Row 2 (Extra) __________ (__________)
```

Is it possible?  Thoughts on converting this to more semantic html would also be entertained.  Also note that I'd like all of the "Row 2" line to be on 1 line when possible, it should work with a flexible table width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a way to get this to format correctly without putting the parentheses in their own cells.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Header</td>
      <td colspan="4"><input /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Target&nbsp;(Actual)</th>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;(</td>
      <td><input /></td>
      <td>)</td>
    </tr>
</table>

table {
    width:27em;
}
table input {
    width:99%;
}
```

When I set the table width to something like 95%, everything resizes nicely with the browser.  A bit of padding on cells keeps the parentheses and inputs from overlapping.

Comment: use box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use CSS for this, I'd just add a second `<td>` element, but you'd have to use some additional CSS for widths, etc.

```
<tr>
  <td>Header</td>
  <td colspan="2"><input style="width: 99.6%" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Header (Extra)</td>
  <td><input style="width: 99.3%" /></td>
  <td>(<input style="width: 99.3%" />)</td>
</tr>
```

*I used the 99.3% for the width because input elements are slightly different and 100% causes it to overflow past the boundaries. I've found 99.3% to work for the best majority of cases in my experience.*

[**Full JSFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/animuson/mHUbX/2/)

Comment: Putting  a single TD with "width:49%" (or so) in each INPUT also seems to work. It's more clean, but also more fragile.

Comment: When messing with widths, any way is fragile when you're not using exact amounts.

Comment: @Chris Marasti-Georg: You'd have to adjust the width of the input fields. Like stated, percentages break easily. Unless you're using exact values (e.g. '100px'), you're going to have problems doing this.